# Sharepoint 2019: problem with the app catalog site

Tags: sharepoint

I am learning Sharepoint 2019. I installed it on our own server (Windows Server 2016 and SQL Server 2017). I was able to create Teams site, Communications site, etc. and they work just fine.

I followed the steps in this MS article to create an App Catalog site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-the-app-catalog

The creation of this site showed no problem, but when opening it (http://mysite:7777/sites/catalog/SitePages/Home.aspx), I got an error page:

```
Sorry, something went wrong
An unexpected error has occurred.
```

It doesn't show any specific reason. I used Chrome to inspect network traffic, and I saw this:

```
Request URL: http://mysite:7777/_api/SP.Web.GetContextWebThemeData?lcid=0
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

This is the only issue I saw in network traffic in Chrome. How can I fix this issue?

### Update

1. For this installation, I used a trial key for Enterprise found here:
   http://vladilen.com/content/sharepoint-keys
2. The port 80 is already used by another app. I created Communications sites and Teamsite sites, and they are running just fine at port 7777.

Comment: IIS is starting to web application port 7777?

Comment: Yes. The port 80 is already used by another app. I created Communications sites and Teamsite sites, and they are running just fine at port 7777.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when I did try "trust it" an app named "sharepoint-connector-confluence.app" and I've created a support ticket on app owner support site https://jira.communardo.de/servicedesk/customer/portal/2/SCP-10597, I'm waiting for a solution.[image]